# add time on each object initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I'm initializing a jQuery notification plugin using the following code. I used setTimeout function to delay each object init.

```
if(applicablePromotions.length > 0){
    applicablePromotions.forEach(function(promo){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.amaran({
                content:{
                    title:'Your Download is Ready!',
                    message:'1.4 GB',
                    info:'my_birthday.mp4',
                    icon:'fa fa-download'
                },
                theme:'awesome ok',
                position:'top left',
                inEffect:'slideRight',
                outEffect:'slideLeft'
            });
        },1000)
    })
}
```

The problem is all the objects get's shown in after the delay time period. There is no time difference in each object. how can I achieve the time difference on each object.

I use the following plugin : http://hakanersu.github.io/AmaranJS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is all the elements in the array is using a constant delay of `1000 ms`, since you want to display one by one, you can use a dynamic delay like

```
if (applicablePromotions.length > 0) {
    applicablePromotions.forEach(function (promo, i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.amaran({
                content: {
                    title: 'Your Download is Ready!',
                    message: '1.4 GB',
                    info: 'my_birthday.mp4',
                    icon: 'fa fa-download'
                },
                theme: 'awesome ok',
                position: 'top left',
                inEffect: 'slideRight',
                outEffect: 'slideLeft'
            });
            //use a dynamic delay
        }, (i + 1) * 1000)
    })
}
```